# Leaderboard in database without login?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm creating a game in Javascript which has a leaderboard.

I initially wanted to just have it so you can enter a `player name` then click `play game`.

The game has a countdown timer so I wanted to post the player score to the database in two scenarios:

1. The timer reaches 0 and the game is over
2. The player gets all the answers correct and completes the game

I would send an object like this:

```
{
 name: 'Fred Smith',
 score: 14
}
```

My question is this sensible without an actual account through register/login?

Because each time someone plays they will post a new score and name for e.g

1. You set your player name to be `Bob`
2. You play once, it inserts a new JS object to the DB
3. You click `play again` and have another game, this will post a new JS object with the name `Bob` and a new score

I'm not too experienced with databases so was curious on if it would be able to manage the size, or if there is a better approach to this without implementing register/login.

Thanks

Comment: From a data perspective it doesn't really make a difference.  From a product perspective be aware that any user can over-write any other user's score by just entering that other user's name.

Comment: Kind of, it wouldn't over-write their score you would just have two objects with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @juliancq answer:

1. a client app (browser) loads in the game.
2. searches for the cookie.
3. if none found, creates a new cookie with unique ID and stores it in the browser (possibly the name of the user too); if cookie exists - parse it to get UID or UID+name.
4. user enters a name (if not parsed from cookie);
5. plays the game until the end-condition.
6. POST request sent to DB of choice.

```
// js (commonJS)
const { v1: uuidv1 } = require("uuid");
const uid = 'uid='.concat(uuidv1());

// the 'SameSite=' parameter could be omitted or set to 'Lax' in some cases
// more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie

const name = "name_from_form";

document.cookie = `${uid}; SameSite=None; Secure`;
document.cookie = `name=${name}; SameSite=None; Secure`;

const uidCookieValue = document.cookie
  .split("; ")
  .find((row) => row.startsWith("uid="))
  ?.split("=")[1];
const nameCookieValue = document.cookie
  .split(";")
  .find((row) => row.startsWith("name="))
  ?.split("=")[1];
```

You can checkout the sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/set-uuid-name-cookies-sw5gt3

P.S. it's a new account so i couldn't comment :)

Comment: Hey thanks for this, I think I thought it would flow like this.

And in the end condition we should grab the cookie uuid from the browser and query the DB to see if this uuid exists in the DB to update the score?

And if the DB finds it update and if it doesn't then we just post a new JS object with a new user + score?

My last question :)

Comment: You could do it the way you've described.
I'm working with Firebase as the db of choice. There, you only need to know the path to the object you're updating/creating; no need to confirm its existence. So you could just punch in the path to the document and press 'send'. For instance you have a collection in FireStore called `user_scores`, which has `uid` you've generated on the client side as the document identifiers and the `{ name: 'Fred Smith', score: 14 }` values. You could call `await setDoc(doc(db, 'user_scores', uid), {score: 17}), {merge: true}`...

Comment: this will create a new object or merge fields (all in the example, but you can fine-tune that) of the payload with an existing one. [here's their docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_lite.md#setdoc_2)

Comment: I think I see,`setDoc` in Firebase checks the `uid` passed here? And if it finds it updates the document because we passed `{merge: true}` and if it doesn't then it will create new object with uid passed?

I'm actually using MongoDB, maybe it has something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: yes. now that i think about it, you'd actually want to send the full new payload every time, just so it doesn't create malformed objects when it creates new ones

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an unique id for each distinct user and store it as a cookie. Then use that id to store in the database.

Comment: How would the flow look?

1. Name set to `Steve`
2. Click `Play Game`
3. Set cookie to unique ID
4. After timer hits 0 or player gets all answers set/update score in DB based on ID

Is something like that correct?

Thanks